# How to structure the snippet and status in JSON for v3 YouTube API upload

Tags: json, http, post, youtube, youtube-api

I'm uploading videos to YouTube using the following API
"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status"
and sending the upload values in "options" object array.

Like this:

```
options.headers = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "mysite.com"
  };

options.snippet = {
                title: 'Video title',
                description: 'Video description',
                tags: 'Video tags',
                categoryId: 22
            };

options.status= {
                privacyStatus: 'private'
            };
```

The video is uploaded with no problem but the snippet and status key values are not sent to YouTube!

What is wrong with my JSON structure? I tried to include the snippet and status under options.part but failed also.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert), the `tags` key needs to be an array of strings, not a single string.  It's possible that passing in a single string is causing the values to be invalidated.

```
tags: [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ]
```

Make an API call for any video on YouTube and you will see the tags are in this format: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

```
options.snippet = {
            title: 'Video title',
            description: 'Video description',
            tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ],
            categoryId: 22
        };
```

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: @user2985035 added an example.

Comment: Please would you apply it to our case, still did not get it sorry

Comment: Yes got your point , but I don't think, because the status does not contain tags.

Comment: @user2985035 Yes, but you also said the `snippet` values were not being sent correctly.  I thought i could be an issue with the tag parameter.  I'll keep thinking of a solution.